# Wi-fi connected, but has no access to internet

Tags: 18.04

I connected my Ubuntu 18.04 to Wi-FI, but cannot have access to internet. That happens only with one particular Network. With others it works fine.

Comment: Start with https://github.com/UbuntuForums/wireless-info

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! You'll need to provide more information such as what type of network is working versus the ones that don't work. For example, are they WPA2 networks, encrypted, signal strength? What wireless hardware are you using, etc.

Comment: Maybe you have to go through an authentication process. Does a `ping 1.1.1.1` on terminal give you any output?